# Programmatically Update MyBatis Configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mybatis

I use the following code to initialize the `MyBatis SQLSessionFactory` for the application that I am working on

**Pseudo-Code**

```
ProviderClass {

    getter () {
     return factory;
    }

    init() {
        final InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream("configuration.xml");
        factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
    }

    refresh() {
        //How should I reload the configuration xml?
    }
}
```

**Question:**
How should I try and reload the configuration?
I have tried the same pattern as init again, but it does not reload the configuration.
Do I have to read directly from the filesystem as opposed to reading resource as a stream?

**Note:** This is only for a development environment where I do not want to redeploy the web-application every time the underlying mapping files change. The application is hot-deployed, so changes to files in the editor do make it to the server.